# How do I set a dependency to jquery with browserify and gulp

Tags: jquery, gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

So I'm using gulp and browserify and I'm requiring jquery and a plugin (owl-carousel) which needs jquery as a dependency.

However the order of the files seems to be somewhat messed up as query is compiled into the final js file after the plugin I'm using which results in the console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

How do I tell browserify that there is a dependency? Do I need browserify-shim for this or is there another way?

My includes:

```
var $             = require('jquery'),
    owlCarousel   = require('./vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.js');
```

I'm also using browserify-shim now but getting same error. This is what's in my package.js:

```
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./vendor/jquery/jquery.js",
    "owlcarousel": "onedirection/static/js/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "owlcarousel": {
      "exports": "owlcarousel",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick to use jquery( $ ) globally on the build version:

```
global.$ = require('jquery');
```

And in the package.json

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": {
      "exports": "$"
    }
  }
```